# A question on "$p$-group bounds"?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Suppose $n_p(G)$ is the number of elements of order $p$ in a group $G$.

Does there for every prime $p$ exist a $\epsilon_p > 0$, such that for any group $G$ $n_p(G) > (1 - \epsilon_p(G))|G|$ implies, that $G$ is a $p$-group?

This question was inspired by a well known fact, that for any group $G$ $n_2(G) > \frac{3}{4}|G|$ implies $G$ being a $2$-group (or, alternatively, that $\epsilon_2 = \frac{1}{4}$).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this is the main theorem of

*Laffey, Thomas J.*, [**The number of solutions of (x^p=1) in a finite group**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100052865), Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 80, 229-231 (1976). [ZBL0343.20006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0343.20006).

Namely, if a finite group $G$ has more than $\tfrac{p}{p+1} |G|$ elements of order $p$, then $G$ is a $p$-group. This bound is achieved by $C_p \ltimes C_2^k$ where $p = 2^k-1$ is a Mersenne prime.

---

There is a related very frustrating problem: Is there an $\delta_p$ such that, if $G$ has more than $1-\delta_p$ elements of order $p$, then $G$ is $p$-torsion? We can take $\delta_3 = \tfrac{2}{9}$, see

*Laffey, Thomas*, [**The number of solutions of (x^3=1) in a 3-group**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01301629), Math. Z. 149, 43-45 (1976). [ZBL0314.20020](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0314.20020).

I thought for a bit that the right bound might be $\tfrac{p-1}{p^2}$ in general, which occurs for $C_p \ltimes \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]/(1-\zeta_p)^N$ where $\zeta_p$ is a $p$-th root of unity and $p \leq N \leq 2p-2$. But that's wrong! Wall constructed a $5$-group of exponent $25$ where all the elements of order $25$ were in an index $25$ subgroup, demonstrating that $\delta_5$, if it exists, is $< \tfrac{1}{25}$.

*Wall, G. E.*, On Hughes’ $H_{p}$ problem, Proc. Int. Conf. Theory Groups, Canberra 1965, 357-362 (1967). [ZBL0189.31701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0189.31701)

But, as far as I know, no one knows whether any such $\delta_5$ exists at all!

See 
*Havas, George; Vaughan-Lee, Michael*, [**On counterexamples to the Hughes conjecture.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2009.04.011), J. Algebra 322, No. 3, 791-801 (2009). [ZBL1187.20010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1187.20010)

for groups achieving $\tfrac{1}{p^2}$ for various $p>5$. I will also note that I talked to Harry Altman about a lot of this material.

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, in the first paragraph of the second paper of Laffey you linked to, he expresses doubt that a $\delta_p$ exists for $p > 3$. Is there a reason you in contrast seem optimistic about its potential existence?

Comment: @SamHopkins I don't think I'm knowledgeable enough to have an opinion. Maybe I'm just an optimist?