# Bounds on the number of elements of a given order in a finite simple group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple group (nonabelian, for simplicity). Let $n(G,k)$ denote the number of elements of $G$ of order $k$. I'm interested in results which bound quantities related to $n(G,k)$.

For example, are there bounds for $\frac{n(G,k)}{|G|}$? For $\frac{n(G,k)}{k}$? For some other reasonable normalization of $n(G,k)$?

Comment: I think we have $n(G,2)\leq\frac34|G|$ and  $n(G,3)\leq\frac78|G|$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Do we expect $n(G,k)$ to be largest for small $k$? (eg $k = 2$?). Is it possible to quantify how the bounds improve as $k$ increases?

Comment: Related question https://mathoverflow.net/q/337477/297 (but without the hypothesis that $G$ is simple, so the answers are pretty different).

Answer (score 8):

For $w$ a word in a free group $F_d$, we can consider the word map $\bar w : G^d \to G$. Let $P_w(G)$ denote the proportion of $d$-tuples $x \in G^d$ such that $\bar w (x) = 1$. Your notation is related by

$$P_{x^k}(G) = \sum_{\ell \mid k} n(G, \ell) / |G|.$$

For any fixed nontrivial word $w$ we have $P_w(G) \to 0$ as $|G| \to \infty$ for nonabelian finite simple groups $G$. [1]

[1] *Dixon, John D.; Pyber, László; Seress, Ákos; Shalev, Aner*, [**Residual properties of free groups and probabilistic methods**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.2003.019), J. Reine Angew. Math. 556, 159-172 (2003). [ZBL1027.20013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1027.20013).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a different, reasonably elementary, proof that  for any $\varepsilon > 0,$ there are only finitely many non-Abelian simple groups $G$ with $n(G,2) > \varepsilon |G|.$

The number of involutions of such a $G$ is $\sum_{\chi \neq 1} \nu(\chi) \chi(1)$ where $\nu$ is the Frobenius-Schur
indicator (which always takes value $0 , 1 $ or $-1$).
This is certainly less than $\frac{|G|}{d},$ where $d$ is the minimum degree of a non-trivial complex irreducible character of $G$.

By Jordan's theorem on complex linear groups, for any positive integer  $n$, there are only finitely many non-Abelian simple groups which have a non-trivial irreducible character of degree $n$, so the claimed result follows.